# Azure DevOps Copying files to Google cloud failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently we were using this extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GlobalFreightSolutionsLtd.copy-files-to-google-buckets) to copy files from Azure to google cloud bucket. After almost one year of use everything was perfect, until we got error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ResumableUploadError: A resumable upload could not be performed. The directory, C:\Users\VssAdministrator.config, is not writable. You may try another upload, this time setting `options.resumable` to `false`.

Maybe someone had similar problem and can help to solve it. Or we should contact product owner to solve the issue? Any other options/suggestions for uploading files are also acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to add resumable: false to your config. Please refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/807#issuecomment-590070540).

Comment: Is this configured at google storage? I can't find where to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message its coming from the Node JS [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage) used to connect to GCP buckets, the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GlobalFreightSolutionsLtd.copy-files-to-google-buckets) is apparently built with this GCP client library, the suggestion mentioned on the [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/807) would need to be implemented by the Developer of the extension, concretely it looks that it may be using the [createWriteStream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) method which according to the doc:

> Resumable uploads require write access to the $HOME directory. Through
> config-store, some metadata is stored. By default, if the directory is
> not writable, we will fall back to a simple upload. However, if you
> explicitly request a resumable upload, and we cannot write to the
> config directory, we will return a ResumableUploadError

I would suggest maybe contacting the extension publisher, or trying to disable resumable uploads within the extension options (if any)